# Using BooleanQuery or write more indexes?

Tags: java, lucene.net, lucene

A category tree like this:

```
root_1
  sub_1
  sub_2
  ... to sub_20
```

Every document has a sub category(like `sub_2`). Now, I only wrote `sub_2` in lucene index:

```
new NumericField("category",...).setIntValue(sub_2.getID());
```

I want to get all `root_1`'s documents, using `BooleanQuery` (merge the `sub_1` to `sub_20`) to search or write an other category in every entry document:

```
new NumericField("category",...).setIntValue(sub_2.getID());
new NumericField("category",...).setIntValue(root_1.getID());//sub_2's ancestor category
```

Which is the better choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a path enumeration/'Dewey Decimal' representation of the category hierarchy. That is, instead of just storing 'sub_2' for the second child of the first root, store instead something like '001.002'.

To find the root and all of its children, you would search on "**category:001***".

To find only the children of the root, you would search on "**category:001.***".

(Please also see [How to store tree data in a Lucene/Solr/Elasticsearch index or a NoSQL db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970193/how-to-store-tree-data-in-a-lucene-solr-elasticsearch-index-or-a-nosql-db/10209230#10209230).)

Comment: I've done this before, except I didn't use IDs, I just stored the name as a path eg `category=root_1/sub_1` etc and then searched for `root_1` using `category:root_1*`